# Selecting a row with unique ID

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I need to select the last row from two datasets. I need the `main_ID` and the `key_ID`. However, the `main_ID` will often have multiple `key_ID`.. in addition to these two rows I need address insertion date and name.

The data comes from table one with `key_ID` and `Main_ID` and name the second joined table has `main_ID` address and insertion_date... the second table has no `key_ID` column

An example is :

```
main_ID   Key_ID  address insertion_date    name
---------------------------------------------------    
123        200    26t      10/09          Hale T.
123        200    26h      10/10          Hale T.
567        200    26h      10/10          Hale T.
```

I want to pull the last row of `Key_ID` with all the columns shown.

So my final output should show:

```
main_ID  Key_ID  address insertion_date name
--------------------------------------------------
567        200    26h      10/10          Hale T.
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  You use `order by main_ID desc` with either `top` or `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window/analytic functions or using aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by main_id) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```